# Count one level group by another level in pandas Multinidex

Tags: python, pandas, count, multi-index

I have a Pandas data frame with three level multi-index, namely date/ID/period/.

| date / ID / period | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01/ 1 / 1 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01/ 1 / 2 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01/ 1 / 3 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01/ 2 / 1 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01/ 2 / 2 | 1 |
| 2020-01-01/ 3 / 2 | 2 |

If I want to filter on the count of id group by date, for example, in this case, how to select all the ID with at least 2 periods as of each date, to get the desired result:

| date / ID | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01/ 1 | 3 |
| 2020-01-01/ 2 | 2 |
| 2020-01-01/ 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `level=[0,1]` in your `.groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'VALUE': {('2020-01-01', 1, 1): 1,
  ('2020-01-01', 1, 2): 2,
  ('2020-01-01', 1, 3): 1,
  ('2020-01-01', 2, 1): 2,
  ('2020-01-01', 2, 2): 1,
  ('2020-01-01', 3, 2): 2}})

df.groupby(level=[0,1]).count()

Out[1]: 
              VALUE
2020-01-01 1      3
           2      2
           3      1
```

Alternatively,

```
df.notnull().sum(level=[0,1])
```